# Kotlin custom dialog Parameter specified as non-null

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I got this error :

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as
>   non-null is null: method
>   kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter
>   savedInstanceState

When i am trying to inflate a custom dialog in Kotlin
, i got the error i wrote above on the super.onCreate line in the dialog.

the dialog code is :

```
class Custom_Dialog_Exit_App(var activity: Activity)// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    : Dialog(activity, R.style.full_screen_dialog) {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_exit_app)
        activity.window!!.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)

        initView()
    }

    fun initView() {
        initClicks()
    }

    fun initClicks() {


    }


}
```

and the init is :

```
val omer = Custom_Dialog_Exit_App(this@MainActivity)
        omer.show()
```

Please help

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {`

Since `savedInstanceState` can be `null` the type has to be `Bundle?`.

When you specify that a parameter is not null then kotlin generates a check in all cases. This includes when implementing a Java interface so you need to be careful about making nullable parameters non-null.

Comment: ty you so much !! you save my day .

Comment: Thanks! The built in Java to Kotlin converter in Android Studio converted it to a non nullable Bundle and this worked.

Answer (score 15):

I also meet the error ,I changed the type `Bundle` to `"Bundle?"`.Then it workd for me. In Kotlin you have to specify if the variable/parameter is null or not.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    init()
}
```

Answer (score -3):

change this line

```
  activity.window!!.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
```

to

```
if(activity.window != null) { 
     activity.window!!.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
               WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) 
} else {
     Log.e(TAG, "Window is null");
}
```

Comment: it is still crashing :/